# How to insert data retrieved from MySQL into array in Android Application?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database, I wrote this code

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$mysql_qry = "select * from domande"; 
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id_domanda'=>$row[0],
'domanda'=>$row[1],
'username'=>$row[2]
));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

It should return an array. I've been able to show the array in a alert dialog in this way:

```
class BackgroundWorkerDomande extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        Context context;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        BackgroundWorkerDomande (Context ctx){
            context = ctx;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String type = params[0];


            if (type=="getquestion"){
                try {


                    URL url = new URL(params[3]);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);


                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String result = "";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Status");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();



        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

but if i wanted to insert the result in a new array declared in my MainActivity how should I do? I just followed some tutorials on internet  to write this code so I don't perfectly know how it works. (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to know exactly what you want since you posted your working code but didn't specify an exact problem. Particularly, what does "insert the result in a new array" mean? Taken at face value, I see this:

```
ArrayList<String> results;
results.add (result);
```

However, I will make one suggestion: in you php code, instead of posting the whole result as one string, can you break it into fields and post those as an array? Then, on the receiving end, if you want to work with the individual field values you won't have to parse them from `result`.